# PHPStorm/Webstorm increase memory to more than 512MB

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, phpstorm, webstorm, windows-7-x64

I'm using `PHPStorm` under `Win7 64bit` with `64bit Java (latest version I guess)` and working currently on an insanely big and chaotic project. There are many classes containing `10k LOC` and more. Therefore my `PHPStorm` runs out of memory once in a while.

I get this nice `Out-of-Memory` dialog suggesting increasing my memory settings. I currently have set in my `PhpStorm.exe.vmoptions`:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

The problem is: When I increase my memory to be used in this file I get the following error when starting the program:

> Failed to create JVM: Error code -4

I Googled around but nobody seems to want the memory to be **more** than `512MB`.

**Does anybody know what I can do to use PHPStorm without any hassle again?**

Sure, I can reset the cache but this is not a permanent solution, right?

I read somewhere that adding this line to my `vmoptions` is a good idea, but I don't see any difference:

```
-server
....
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using 64-bit Java? What "Help | About" says about Java version used? *"I googled around but nobody seems to want the memory to be more than 512MB"* -- that's correct GC will be quite annoying.

Comment: wtf...you are right, it says java x86. Why is PHPStorm not taking the main java installed on the system?

Comment: Because **1)** PhpStorm comes with bundled x86 Java and it is the first one that it tries; only then it looks for other Java installations -- check `PhpStorm.bat` for details (what environment variables and in which order. **2)** You should use `PhpStorm64.exe` and not `PhpStorm.exe` (same for `.vmoptions` file -- it should be `PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: **NOTE:** I'm talking about PhpStorm **v8** (currently in EAP stage) and not v7 -- which does not have those 64-bit specific files.

Comment: ah! ok... well :) is v8 stable enough for working with it?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? It works OK for me (rather small projects).. but I have no clue how it will behave on your computer/projects (**especially considering your requirements**) -- it's an EAP build after all -- not all code is optimised for speed and memory consumption (I'm sure you know how software development works: working feature first -- optimisations later).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure that PhpStorm use 64-bit Java and not bundled one (which is 32-bit). You an check that in `Help | About`.

Generally speaking: with 64-bit Java you do not have to change that value as it works **a bit** differently compared to 32-bit one.

**1)** PhpStorm comes with bundled x86 Java and it is the first one that it tries; only then it looks for other Java installations -- check `PhpStorm.bat` for details (what environment variables and in which order). By defining one of those environment variables (which will point to your 64-bit Java installation) you can tell PhpStorm to use instead of bundled one.

**2)** PhpStorm **v8** (currently in EAP stage) comes with 64-bit specific files: you should use `PhpStorm64.exe` and not `PhpStorm.exe` (same for `.vmoptions` file -- it should be `PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions`).

I'm not sure how PhpStorm v7 works with 64-bit Java -- have never tried it this way myself.

---

**Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under**

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: I seems that it doesn't like the 64bit at all. I added the `WEBIDE_JDK` enviroment var and now nothing is happening when I want to start the program...

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under -- maybe you have provided **wrong path**?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the right path... But the v8 seems to work and I can manipulate the memory settings! Do you know if this option is good to use: `XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15`?

Comment: Sorry -- not a Java/JVM person, at all.

Comment: In order to solve this one it was a combination of this answer and the bottom answer.

Comment: Thank for information, I just do this for WebStorm and it's working better now.

Comment: I had an 81MB xdebug profiler output I tried to open in PhpStorm 9.0.2. After over 10 minutes of trying, it gave me "out of memory" error. I realized I was running 32 bit PHPS. I increased Xmx to 2048 from 512, but then PHPS32 wouldn't start an all (why?). I tried PHPS64, but I was missing the JDK, so it wouldn't start either. After installing 64 bit JDK from here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), PHPS64 started, but still ran out of memory after 10 minutes with default Xms of 750. But after I increased Xms to 2048, the profile opened in 2s!

Answer (score 108):

Changing memory settings for PHPStorm now has a menu option:

[image]

Comment: Good hint but the problem was that we couldn't increase the memory because of the 32bit limitations.

Comment: I know, but though that maybe someone will need only to change memory and because SO is already like devs wiki.

Comment: thanks, i got a $3k macbook pro with 16gb ram still slows down after 2-3 hours of work, increased to 2.5gb let's see how this works out.

Answer (score 36):

After reading this post, I switched to 64bit version (after installing correct JDK) and increased designated memory to 2GB just to shut it up. But I still hit the ceiling, freezes et.c.

Eventually realized, that I had my `bower_components`folder tracked. Folders like this with tons of javascript-files et.c. will basically eat all ram in the world (I also exclude `node_modules` folder now, same story). So I **right-clicked the `node_modules` folder > Mark directory as > Exluded**. After some garbage-collection, bumped PhpStorm's memory footprint down to 5-600mb, which seems reasonable.

Comment: Crazy memory/cpu usage has been killing me for weeks.  This fixed it right away.  Thanks!

Comment: Currently you must set the environment variable for the jdk OR edit the startup batch file.  Then you must always start Webstorm with a batch file to use x64 (as of now).  Here are IntelliJ's instructions for switching to the 64-bit JDK:  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: yup  mark directory -> excluded is a life saver, this needs to be in JetBrains docs

Comment: Wow.... excluding vendor & giant asset folders. . . saved the day instantly, thanks! (PhpStorm)

Comment: Few years ago excluding directories worked for me very well. But with 2022 version I had to really delete logs and other temp files from excluded directories to reduce memory usage. However it's different with node_modules: excluding this directory helps.

Answer (score 11):

**PhpStorm 2016.1 and newer**

As of PhpStorm 2016.1 instead of `WEBIDE_JDK_64` one should use `JAVA_HOME` environment variable that should point to your JVM path.

**Versions prior PhpStorm 2016.1**

Like it was mentioned in the @LazyOne's answer, as of PhpStorm v8 (already released), you can use PhpStorm64.exe. But I wasn't able to find any description on how to specify the JVM path for it. The document that explains how to select the JDK version, seems to be a bit outdated.

After some research, I discovered that you should create `WEBIDE_JDK_64` environment variable that should point to the JRE 64-bit installation path. After doing this, you will be able to start PhpStorm64.exe.

By default it sets max memory to `750mb`. If you need more, you can modify the `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8\bin\PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions`. The better idea, however, would be to edit your user's vmoptions file. Just copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 8\bin\PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions` to `%USERPROFILE%\.IntelliJIdea12\idea.vmoptions` and set `-Xmx750m` to a higher value.

Answer (score 6):

Simply `File` > `Invalidates Caches / Restart...` works for me.

Comment: Thx for the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

`Help -> Change Memory Settings -> Update Maximum Heap Size` to desired value. This fixed issue for me.

Comment: maybe this is the modern way to go. my post is quite ancient :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a log file in the application which grew from a few KB to over 2 GB during a few seconds due to a bug.  Webstorm was trying to index this 2 GB log file and running out of memory.  Deleting the log file solved the problem (and then fixing the bug prevented the log file from growing).

Prior to this I also tried running the x64 JDK and increasing XMX to 2048.  But in the end a 64 bit environment with 2048 MB wasn't enough (even though 512 MB was always enough before).