# Choose jdk for WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'd like to specify jdk for my **WebStorm 8**, but I can't find a place, where can I do it.

I installed **jdk** **1.7** and **1.8**, specified `JAVA_HOME`, `WEBIDE_HOME`, but webstorm.exe still looking into `../jre` folder.

**Update**
OS - windows 7 x64

After restarting PC still used `../jre`.

[image: '']

Comment: isn't webstorm just for web developement?

Comment: @OliverWatkins, yes, but this ide is written in java, so it needed jvm to run environment. By default it uses `../jre`, but I'd like t o override it with jdk

Comment: What do you see when you execute `SET` in console (cmd.exe)? If you have setup it correctly .. but IDE does not picks it up -- try logging off and on again (or just restart PC).

Comment: @LazyOne, After `SET` I see `WEBIDE_JDK=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67`

Comment: Should work then -- it's the first environment variable it checks when searching for JDK (I'm checking it with PhpStorm .. but AFAIK it still uses the same variables in the same order: `WEBIDE_JDK, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME`).

Comment: If it does not pick it up .. and you have already tried restarting your PC .. then I may only suggest this "trick": just delete (or rename) bundled `jre` folder -- launcher will keep looking for other variables.

Comment: One Q though: Do you have 32 bit OS? Possibly (based on the java path you gave earlier) you are trying to use 64-bit Java with 32-bit launcher?

Comment: @LazyOne, I have windows 7 x64 and tried jdk7 and 8 x64.
I also tried to rename jre folder, but have a message like `jdk not found'

Comment: So -- you have installed x64 bit Java, right? 1) Which java version do you WANT it to use: 32-bit or 64-bit? 2) What file do you launch -- `WebStorm.exe` or what?

Comment: @LazyOne, I use WebStorm.exe. I have installed 64-bit version of jdk

Comment: OK -- I'm downloading WebStorm now to check something (since it could be different from PhpStorm which I'm using). Give me like 5-10 mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To run IDE using 64-bit JDK** you have to launch IDE using `WebStorm64.exe` file instead of default `WebStorm.exe`.

Small "problem" is: WebStorm **v8** does not contain `*64.exe` file as part of the distribution package -- it only available in **v9** (currently in [EAP stage](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/webstorm-9-eap/)).

To run v8 using 64-bit JDK you have to use **.BAT** file (`WebStorm.bat`) to launch IDE:
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/450063

Related/Kind-of-similar (for PhpStorm): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546908/783119

---

**P.S. Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under**

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still will use webstorm x86, I don't like .bat files :) But I installed x86 jdk version and it works. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: FYI, In webstorm 9 there is *64.exe file.

Comment: @baxxabit I know -- my answer clearly states that: *"only available in v9..."*