# PHPstorm freezes very often

Tags: phpstorm

I have PHPStorm, but when I'm writing native function (for example str_poss, return, parent...) it very often freeze for about 10 seconds. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. But it happen to me on Windows7 and on Ubuntu also. Has anyone same trouble? Thanks.

Comment: **1)** Where project files / source files are located -- local HDD/SSD or over network? **2)** How much memory IDE consumes? You can enable displaying memory indicator in status bar -- check Settings screen -- look for `Show memory indicator` (should be under `Appearance` section). I've noticed such freezes (much shorter though: 1-2 sec) when GC (garbage collector) does the job when memory is near limit.

Comment: I have the same problem with PHPStorm 8. However I noticed it depends somehow on the size of the project I am working on. If anyone has a solution so far please let us know.

Comment: Found a hint right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546022/phpstorm-increase-memory-to-more-than-512mb . So I installed the 64-bit JDK and now using PhpStorm64.exe . So far did not encountered any problem.

Comment: I have found that PHPStorm 2020.2 freezes and hangs when dealing with SQL Union language injection in PHP pages.

Answer (score 30):

PHPStorm used to "lag" for me before quite often too... but I managed to fix it in the following ways (It did take a bit of tweaking/experimenting though to get it to work!  But now it is blazing fast once again!)

Here is what I did to optimize it:
1) If you are on Linux - Make sure you are using Oracle Java on your system, not Open JDK
From: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under it says: 
On windows: "JDK is bundled with all the product installers and it's recommended that you will use the provided JDK version unless there are any specific issues.

32-bit JDK is located in IDE_HOME\jre directory and is used by the 32-bit product executable.

To run the IDE in 64-bit mode you will need to download and install 64-bit JDK (not JRE) distribution and install it yourself. IDE will find and use it from the registry when you run the 64-bit .exe file (available only for IntelliJ IDEA right now, other products can use the .bat file to run in 64-bit mode)."

2) Disable any plugins you do not ABSOLUTELY NEED!  Especially any 3rd party plugins you may have installed**

GBC from [PhpStorm 7 very slow and sluggish on netbook, optimize IDE for responsiveness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842924/phpstorm-7-very-slow-and-sluggish-on-netbook-optimize-ide-for-responsiveness) also had some insties:

3)    Disable language injections: File -> Settings -> Language injections. un-check as many boxes as you're comfortable with. HTML was the real killer for me.

4) Disable inspections: File -> Settings -> Inspections. uncheck as many as you don't need.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am using WebStorm 10.0.4 on Ubuntu 14 on 64bit 8GB machine. It freezes for a few seconds when I type anything. The above suggestion to disabled all plugins not needed solved my problems. Thanks!

Comment: `Make sure you are using Oracle Java on your system, not Open JDK` for those who don't know how to validate this: Go to "Help"->"About" tehre you can see if you use Open JDK or noth

Answer (score 14):

I am on a mounted VM drive and everytime I was going back to PHPStorm it freezes for 5-10 sec.

Unchecked the box "Synchronize files on frame activation", in Settings > General > Synchronization, seems to solve the issue for me.

PHPStorm 7.1 on Linux

Answer (score 10):

A solution I found which drastically increased my speed without having to disable any plugins or disable inspections (because they are useful - why would you want to disable them) was to enable OpenGL.

First of all go to: `path-to-phpstorm\bin\PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions`

Then add these two lines below the others:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd 
-Dawt.java2d.opengl=true
```

This helped me to get that 'eye' logo disappear and show a green tick on 6000 line file in 3 seconds rather than 2 minutes. Amazing how much difference it made.

Comment: I'm curious, what it actually does?

Comment: @TomášVotruba First one would change font aliasing and thus impact how much time editor spends on rendering text, while the other sets backed Java uses to draw 2D on the screen.

Comment: What was OS on which those settings helped?

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

I'm not sure it helped (too far in the past), but I use always the very latest Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using JetBrains Toolbox, go into the Settings beside PhpStorm and crank up the "Maximum heap size". I find about 3000 MB is good.

[image]

If you're *not* using Toolbox, find and open `phpstorm64.vmoptions` and add this line:

```
-Xmx3000m
```

It does the same thing.

Comment: You can also set this in the IDE: `Help/Change Memory Settings`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu. The IDE was freezing regularly on two different PCs (Using a desktop pc at home and a laptop at work), both have as OS Ubuntu 18. The freezing time was about 1-2 minutes.

It stopped after I restart IDE with VM-option: -Dawt.ime.disabled=true

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1923

Answer (score 0):

I had this freezing problem every time I switch to a browser and return back on PHPStorm. It was for a specific project. The IDE stop responding / freze for 3-5 seconds.

I investigated in the the project folder under the PHPStorm `.idea` folder.

The file `workspace.xml` was supposed to have XML in it but it was completely filled by empty strings... just corrupted. I just deleted the file and restarted PHPStorm.

And the freezing problem was solved.

I suspect PHPStorm was unexpectedly closed due to a power outage or blue screen.